# Rotating a map using leaflet js library

Tags: maps, openlayers, leaflet, image-rotation

I need a map rotation feature just like the one available from openLayers 3 (check example below):

http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/drag-rotate-and-zoom.html

Is there a way to do the same thing using the leafletjs library, or perhaps, using a custom plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't currently support map rotation, because it wouldn't be supported by its full range of browsers. This also isn't supported by plugins, since rotation logic would need to be implemented in Leaflet core.

Comment: Is there anything new on this? Mapbox for mobile does support rotation