# Leaflet - top side of map always points to heading direction of a sensor

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm developing a basic leaflet map that updates periodically based on latlng and heading of a sensor.

I've got the marker updating based on latitude and longitude inputs, now I need to adjust the view so that the top always represents the direction of the sensor (heading).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with leaflet

See [Rotating a map using leaflet js library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875857/rotating-a-map-using-leaflet-js-library)

There seems to be other possibilities if this is a major requirement: http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/drag-rotate-and-zoom.html